# Как работает программа для определения простых чисел?

Tags: c

Программа нужна для определения простых чисел.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, n, isPrime;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    isPrime = n > 1 && (n % 2 || n == 2);
    for (i = 3; isPrime && i * i <= n; i += 2) isPrime = n % i;
    puts(isPrime ? "prime" : "Not prime");
    return 0;
}
```

Не до конца понимаю, что делает строка, начинающаяся с for.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> for (i = 3; isPrime && i * i <= n; i += 2) isPrime = n % i;
> ```

Здесь заложен бесхитростный алгоритм вида «перебираем все нечётные числа пока не найдём то, на которое делится `n` или не дойдём до sqrt(n) (*i=sqrt(n)* ⇔ *i²=n*)», сдобренный небольшим количеством Сишной магии.

Из магии здесь, пожалуй, только то, что в Си все не-нулевые целые значения являются логической истиной, а нулевые, соответственно, — ложью. А ещё то, что цикл `for` пригоден не только для обхода массива.

Также не стоит забывать тот банальный факт, что остаток от деления равен нулю тогда и только тогда, когда делимое нацело делится на делитель.

А чтобы понять логику и последовательноть действий всю это строчку можно переписать с помощью `while`:

```
i = 3;
while (isPrime && i*i <= n) {
  int div = n % i;

  if (div!=0) {
    isPrime = 1; // true
  } else {
    isPrime = 0; // false
  }

  i += 2;
}
```

Comment: Тернарный оператор с `false` и `true` в результатах - это какая-то странная необъяснимая избыточная манера. Где вы видели такое "обычно пользуются"? Когда нужно нормализовать результат до `0/1` или `false/true` пользуются операторами сравнения `isPrime = n % i != 0;`. А лепить поверх этого еще и `?:` - это ужас какой-то.

Comment: @AnT, мда... соглашусь... меня с этим что-то занесло...